# Where is the mysql database saved when using docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

Where is my databse saved when I create it in MYSQL through docker?

I created a SQL server with docker by running the following command:

```
sudo docker run --name toms-sql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

However

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in the container. You can mount the mysql data folder to a local folder like this

```
docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql
```